# Azure Monitoring Database performance

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-backups

I need to compile the following information: "a scheduled report that shows the DB environment state. From free space to performance, failed jobs and anything else that can cause a DB not to function correctly."

I keep getting referred to the same learn.microsoft links but for some reason i just get progressively more confused.

Can someone please help me with a step by step instruction on how to achieve the above mentioned?

All our DBs are on Azure VMs.

I tried Chat GPT for the disk sizes and it gave me a Power Shell code. <

```
# Connect to your Azure account
Connect-AzAccount

# Get a list of all virtual machines in your subscription
$vms = Get-AzVM

# Loop through the list of virtual machines
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
  # Get the details of each virtual machine
  $vmName = $vm.Name
  $vmSize = $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize

  # Get a list of all disks attached to the virtual machine
  $disks = Get-AzDisk | Where-Object { $_.ManagedBy -eq $vm.Id }

  # Loop through the list of disks
  foreach ($disk in $disks) {
    # Get the details of each disk
    $diskName = $disk.Name
    $diskSize = $disk.DiskSizeGB
    $diskType = $disk.StorageAccountType

    # Print the virtual machine, disk, and disk size information
    Write-Output "VM Name: $vmName"
    Write-Output "VM Size: $vmSize"
    Write-Output "Disk Name: $diskName"
    Write-Output "Disk Size: $diskSize GB"
    Write-Output "Disk Type: $diskType"
    Write-Output ""
  }
}
```

\>

I could not get free space information or Database information this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is working but you are retrieving information about the VMs, not about the SQL Server that is stored within the VMs.

You need to login into the SQL Server inside the VM and run the query that you want:

```
# Load the Azure RM module
Import-Module AzureRM

# Login to Azure
Login-AzureRmAccount

# Get a list of all Azure VMs
$vms = Get-AzureRmVM

# Loop through each VM
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    # Get the VM's IP address
    $ipAddress = (Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name ($vm.Name + '-ip')).IpAddress

    # Connect to SQL Server on the VM
    $connectionString = "Server=$ipAddress;Database=master;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>"
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $connection.Open()

    # Execute the SELECT @@VERSION query
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = "SELECT @@VERSION"
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()

    # Display the result
    while ($reader.Read()) {
        Write-Output $reader.GetValue(0)
    }

    # Close the connection
    $connection.Close()
}
```

Note that you will need to replace `<username>` and `<password>` with the actual SQL Server login credentials for each VM.

Replace the `"SELECT @@VERSION"` with the query that investigates:

1. DB environment state
2. free space
3. performance
4. failed jobs
5. anything else...